# php code snippet, return two arrays from one recursive function, my solution

Tags: php, arrays, directory, directory-structure, file-manager

Here´s my recent result for recursive listing of a user directory.
I use the results to build a filemanger (original screenshots).

[image: mac-like-filemanger current result]
<sub>(source: [ddlab.de](http://ddlab.de/stackoverflow/mac-like-fm/mac-like-fm.jpg))</sub>

Sorry, the 654321.jpg is uploaded several times to different folders, thats why it looks a bit messy.

[image: mac-like-filemanger current result]
<sub>(source: [ddlab.de](http://ddlab.de/stackoverflow/mac-like-fm/mac-like-fm_2.jpg))</sub>

Therefor I need two separate arrays, one for the directory tree, the other for the files.

Here only showing the php solution, as I am currently still working on javascript for usability. The array keys contain all currently needed infos. The key "tree" is used to get an ID for the folders as well as a CLASS for the files (using jquery, show files which are related to the active folder and hide which are not) a.s.o.

The folder list is an UL/LI, the files section is a sortable table which includes a "show all files"-function, where files are listed completely, sortable as well, with path info.

The function

```
function build_tree($dir,$deep=0,$tree='/',&$arr_folder=array(),&$arr_files=array()) {
    $dir = rtrim($dir,'/').'/'; // not really necessary if 1st function call is clean
    $handle =  opendir($dir); 
    while ($file = readdir($handle)) 
    { 
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") 
        { 
            if (is_dir($dir.$file))
            { 
                $deep++;
                $tree_pre = $tree; // remember for reset
                $tree = $tree.$file.'/'; // bulids something like "/","/sub1/","/sub1/sub2/"
                $arr_folder[$tree] = array('tree'=>$tree,'deep'=>$deep,'file'=>$file);
                build_tree($dir.$file,$deep,$tree,$arr_folder,$arr_files); // recursive function call
                $tree = $tree_pre; // reset to go to upper levels
                $deep--; // reset to go to upper levels
            }
            else 
            {
                $arr_files[$file.'.'.$tree] = array('tree'=>$tree,'file'=>$file,'filesize'=>filesize($dir.$file),'filemtime'=>filemtime($dir.$file));
            } 
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    return array($arr_folder,$arr_files); //cannot return two separate arrays
}
```

Calling the function

```
$build_tree = build_tree($udir); // 1st function call, $udir is my user directory
```

Get the arrays separated

```
$arr_folder = $build_tree[0]; // separate the two arrays
$arr_files = $build_tree[1]; // separate the two arrays
```

see results

```
print_r($arr_folder);
print_r($arr_files);
```

It works like a charme,
Whoever might need something like this, be lucky with it.

I promise to post the entire code, when finished :-)

Comment: This isn't really a site for posting code snippets: it's a Question and Answer site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't a question

Comment: @Mark: isn´t it for sharing ideas and knowledge too ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Mark: will improve my behavior, OK ? :-)